# Probability of a natural 21 in blackjack (using R) is dropping all combinations of "10 diamonds", "10 hearts", "10 spades", etc. WHY?

Tags: r, probability, mean

I am trying to use R to find the probability that I get a natural 21 in Blackjack (i.e., one ace card and one face card).

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtools)

## step 1: build a deck of cards

suit<-c("diamonds","clubs","hearts","spades")

number<-c("ace","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king")

expand<-expand.grid(number=number, suit=suit)

deckofcards<-paste(expand$number,expand$suit)

## step 2: build a vector to be compared against

aces <- paste("ace", suit)
facecard <- c("king", "queen", "jack", "10")
facecard <- expand.grid(num = facecard, suit = suit)
facecard <- paste(facecard$num, facecard$suit)
```

Here is what **aces** and **facecard** looks like:

[image]

```
## find probability of one aces and one facecard

hands <- combinations(52, 2, v=deckofcards) # all possible hands

mean(hands[,1] %in% aces & hands[,2] %in% facecard) # this is the probability
```

My code produces a probability of 0.0361991, but it should be 0.04826546. I figured out that there is a problem in the last line that is failing to read **"10 diamonds", "10 hearts", "10 spades", "10 clubs"**. You can see it here:

```
## find the problem: there should be 64 obs

hands_df<-as.data.frame(hands)
ggg<- hands_df %>% filter(hands[,1] %in% aces & hands[,2] %in% facecard)
```

You will see that **"ggg"** has 48 observations, while it should have 64. Something is omitting all the 16 rows or combinations that have **"10 diamonds", "10 hearts"**, etc.

If I replace "10" in the *number* vector and *facecard*  to **"ten"** then it works fine and gives me the right probability and dataframe (64 obs).

**But I don't understand why the character "10" is not being accepted, and where in the code it is not being accepted? Both "10" and "ten" are exactly the same thing: characters. So what is the problem here?**

Comment: Include the argument `stringsAsFactors = F` in your calls to `expand.grid`. The issue could be conversion to  factor.

Comment: The problem is you are only checking for an ace in the first column and a face card in the second. But that's not the only way to get a black jack. you can also have a face card in the first column, and an ace in the second. You should be doing `mean(hands[,1] %in% aces & hands[,2] %in% facecard | hands[,2] %in% aces & hands[,1] %in% facecard)`. You can see that with `combinations(3, 2, v=c("A","B", "C"))`. You only see unique combinations so AC appears but CA does not.

Comment: @MrFlick Hi yeah I know that - but the "combination" function does that for us. It only lists one of the combinations. And it always lists numerically and then alphabetically. So, "Ace -" & "Queen-" comes first, and there is no need to look for "Queen-" & "Ace-" as that combo is already counted. ```mean(hands[,1] %in% aces & hands[,2] %in% facecard | hands[,2] %in% aces & hands[,1] %in% facecard)``` returns the same probability, because ```mean(hands[,2] %in% aces & hands[,1] %in% facecard)``` is 0. So this whole thing is not the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick If you substitute "ten" in place of "10" the whole thing works and gives the correct probability of 0.04826546. Can you please give it a run and see what's going on.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Just tried that, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MrFlick I stand corrected. Thanks! I didn't know about the lexographical hierarchy as pointed out by IceCream Toucan in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MrFlick is correct. You are assuming the combination will be in a particular order, but it may not be. It is true that the output of `cominations` is ordered already, but a facecard char value can be lexographically greater or less than an ace card, so some pairs will have the ace first and some will have the facecard first. You still have to check both (or compare against a set of pre-ordered pairs)

```
'10 diamonds' > 'ace diamonds'
# [1] FALSE
'king diamonds' > 'ace diamonds'
# [1] TRUE
```

Here you can see that `'ace diamonds'` can be in either of the two columns, one side for `'10 diamonds'` and anohter for `'king diamonds'`, as you would expect based on the comparisons above.

```
hands %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), str_detect, 'ace'),
         if_all(everything(), str_detect, 'diamonds'))

#              V1             V2
# 1   10 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 2    2 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 3    3 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 4    4 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 5    5 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 6    6 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 7    7 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 8    8 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 9    9 diamonds   ace diamonds
# 10 ace diamonds  jack diamonds
# 11 ace diamonds  king diamonds
# 12 ace diamonds queen diamonds
```

Changing the code to check both gives the expected result

```
mean((hands[,1] %in% aces & hands[,2] %in% facecard) |
       (hands[,2] %in% aces & hands[,1] %in% facecard)) # this is the probability
# [1] 0.04826546
```

If you're familiar with the multivariate hypergeometric distribution, you could also skip a whole lot of coding by using a package that has a function for that

```
library(extraDistr)

dmvhyper(c(1, 1, 0), (52/13)*c(1, 4, 8), 2)
# [1] 0.04826546
```

Comment: Oh ... I had no knowledge of the "char value can be lexographically greater or less" matter. Damn this had me pulling my hair for so long. Ok so, if I had instead wrote "ten", then all ace cards would have been arranged in the first hand before all "ten-" cards, right? Because it is ordered that way? So "ace clubs" (hand1) & "ten clubs" (hand2) would be the first combination and we would not have the reverse "ten clubs" & "ace clubs"?